# How do I delete the first character of a line if matches using sed?

Tags: sed

I have a text file with this in it:

#[multilib]

I want to delete the # from the line if #[multilib] exists exactly.

I tried:

`sed -i 's/^#[multilib]/[multilib]/'`

and it doesn't remove the # from the line.`

Comment: is `[multilib]` a literal string that exists in your file?

Comment: Yes, its just text.

Answer (score 4):

The `[` and `]` characters are special in regular expressions. To match the literal string, they need to be escaped:

```bsh
sed -i 's/^#\[multilib\]/[multilib]/' file
# or
sed -i -E 's/^#(\[multilib\])/\1/' file
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: The `]` is only special if it follows an unescaped `[` so you could save a char: `\[multilib]`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `-i` is a non-standard and non-portable `sed` option inspired from `perl`'s `-i`. Here you could also use `perl` directly:

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = substr($_, 1) if rindex($0, "#[multilib]", 0)' file
```

Or with regexps:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^#(?=\[multilib\])//' file
```

Where `(?=...)` is a *positive look-ahead* operator, so it removes a leading `#` as long as it's followed  by `[multilib]`. In perl regex like in sed regexps, `[`, `]` are operators, which you can escape with `\` but also with `\Q[multilib]\E`.